# elements[i].onkeyup = function( ) only fires for first class element

Tags: javascript

Long story short, this is my third time posting on Stackoverflow within 24 hours. Nonethless, I am getting closer to my answer, but I am stuck on one little thing.

Basically, I am using Cocoon, which can help with nested forms, so I when a user wants to create another item, she will have to submit 2 forms, thus, there will be more than 1 item with the same class.

Here is my code.

```
var stopTimeElement = document.getElementsByClassName('mdl-textfield__input stage-time stop_time');

for (var i=0; i<stopTimeElement.length; i++){
  stopTimeElement[i].onkeyup = function() { 
    debugger;
    var stopTimeVal = parseInt(this.value)
    var index = parseInt($(currentStage()).attr('rel')) - 1
    stopTimeArray[index] = stopTimeVal
    wtf = stopTimeArray;
    console.log('----wtf----: ',wtf)
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
    updateTTH();
    //reRun();
  }
}
```

So in the first form, it works properly. But for all the other ones, it does NOT even get triggered. :(

I even tried wrapping in a function as such...

```
function reRun() {
  // code here
}

reRun()
```

I know it's a bit messy with the remixed JavaScript and jQuery but let me know what you have in mind!

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard scopes visibility issue in js. You should just  wrap you inner function into *iife*.

```
for (var i=0; i<stopTimeElement.length; i++){
  (function (i) {
    stopTimeElement[i].addEventListener("keyup", function() { 
        debugger;
        var stopTimeVal = parseInt(this.value)
        var index = parseInt($(currentStage()).attr('rel')) - 1
        stopTimeArray[index] = stopTimeVal
        wtf = stopTimeArray;
        console.log('----wtf----: ',wtf)
        componentHandler.upgradeDom();
        updateTTH();
        //reRun();
    });
  })(i);
}
```

**Update 1**

I've created a simple example of what you are trying to achieve. Maybe it will help to understand what might be wrong in the context of you code, because here I can't see full picture.

```js
let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
console.log(boxes);

for(box of boxes) {
 box.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
     alert(this.id);
    });
}
```

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: darkgray;
}

.box:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<input id="1" class="box"></input>
<input id="2" class="box"></input>
<input id="3" class="box"></input>
<input id="4" class="box"></input>
```

Comment: I honestly thought that would work, but same thing. Didn't do a thing for the second form :(

Comment: @dsomel21, Well. I lost from my sight that you are assigning event handler directly to onkeyup property. I changed my answer with use of ```addEventListener()``` method use.

Comment: @dsomel21, I've added additional example, so you can check out it in my answer.

Comment: This is super helpful, I am kinda curious to why you didn't wrap in a self-invoking function() though. Is it because you don't have an index to reference?

Comment: @dsomel21, Because I dont have here any scoped data. If you will prefer to use indices you and will use them inside of event handler manipulations, you will still be needed to wrap it into iife, if I'm not mistaken. At least, additional level of iife will not make worse.

Comment: @dsomel21, If you get an answer, you can mark it with this green checkbox mark. :)